# Big Maildir mailspool - looking for ways to improve performance

Tags: filesystems, backup, optimization, maildir

I have an extremely large Maildir which contains emails going back many years. I need to rebuild the server and would like to improve the mail storage setup.

My main problem is that backups of the mailspool take an extremely long time: Bacula often takes half a day to run, because of all the small files. I'm also finding that accessing folders can take a while, especially if they have a lot of messages in them.

The Maildirs are in the user home directory, in ~/Maildir. /home is on an Ext4 journaled filesystem. At the moment the system is on a spinning hard drive, but I'm looking to switch to an SSD.

I'm planning to split up the emails into separate accounts (vhost style) so my laptop doesn't end up locally caching a huge number of mail directories, but are there any ways I can improve performance on a general basis -- or even just speeding up the backup run?

I'd considered moving the mailspool onto ZFS, taking a snapshot, then backing up from the snapshot. I think this would fix the backup failures (as I'd be backing up from a consistent, frozen state) and improve reliability (from ZFS's data block checksumming) but that may also cost me performance.

I'd also thought about putting the mailspool in a filesystem (e.g. Ext4) inside a file on a ZFS, taking a snapshot, and backing up the filesystem. In theory that should make the backup very fast, but means I'm effectively taking a sector image of a mounted filesystem, which is indeterminate by its nature.